# Does "declare the most abstract type" increase coupling actually?

Tags: java, object-oriented, interfaces, coupling

According to [Why define a Java object using interface (e.g. Map) rather than implementation (HashMap)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225674/why-define-a-java-object-using-interface-e-g-map-rather-than-implementation), I know I should declare the most abstract type possible, so for example:

```
public interface Fruit{
}

public class Orange extends Fruit{
}
```

when declaring Orange, I should write "Fruit obj=new Orange();" instead of "Orange obj=new Orange();". However, does the "declare the most abstract type" version has higher coupling actually? Because I think "coupling" of a class is about counting how many other class names appeared in the source file, for example:

Declare the most abstract type : other class names appeared : Fruit, Orange, String (3 classes):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Fruit obj=new Orange();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Declare the exact type : other class names appeared : Orange, String (2 classes):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Orange obj=new Orange();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

As "declare the most abstract type" contains 3 other class names, so I think the "declare the most abstract type" has higher coupling than the one that declare the exact type (only 2 class names). Is it true? If not, what is the misconception here? How can a class contains the name of other class but not depending on that class?

Note: the question is just about coupling, neither encourage nor discouraging "declaring most abstract type". Also another reason that I think "Fruit obj=new Orange();" has more coupling is, when one day Orange doesn't extends from Fruit anymore:

```
public class Orange{
}
```

"Fruit obj=new Orange();" needs changing to "Orange obj=new Orange();" to recompile, while "Orange obj=new Orange();" doesn't need to.

Comment: First, this is mainly important for your inputs and outputs, not local variables. Second, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237113/why-are-interfaces-more-helpful-than-superclasses-in-achieving-loose-coupling

Comment: "Because I think "coupling" of a class is about counting how many other class names appeared in the source file" Spoiler: it's not, at least not as simplistically as you do it here.

Comment: Well, you can't really understand this by looking at the `main` function, as `main` is really "glue" code. You'd actually have something like a separate class (or even just a function) that takes in a Fruit, and expresses all of it's logic in terms of Fruit (never mentioning any derived type). That other class is decoupled from the concrete types. Note however, that just having a class extend an interface is not enough to decouple its clients from it. It's the kinds of methods you choose to put on that interface that allow for decoupling (or not).

Comment: Another thing to consider here is that the `Orange` class is already coupled to the Fruit interface.  That is that changes to the `Fruit` interface will generally require changes to the `Orange` class.  By depending on `Orange`, you've got a transitive dependency on Fruit whether you import it or not.

Comment: @JimmyJames By depending on `Fruit` and not in any explicit way on `Orange` you are so loosely coupled to `Orange` that you are independently deployable.

Comment: @candied_orange I don't follow.  How do you compile `Orange` if it isn't a valid `Fruit`?

Comment: @JimmyJames You compile the using code without telling it that `Orange` exists. Both the using code and `Orange` know `Fruit` exists but not each other. `Fruit` doesn't know either one exists. Do it that way and different teams of Devs can develop these independently so long as they agree on `Fruit`.

Comment: @candied_orange I don't really see your point.  If you change `Fruit` (the only scenario that matters) you will need change `Orange` or your compilation will fail, or you will get a runtime error.

Comment: @JimmyJames I can compile `Fruit` using code that has never heard of an `Orange`. It wont do much until some other complication unit hands it an `Orange` but it will compile just fine.

Comment: @candied_orange `Orange` won't compile.  How are you going to load the `Orange` class that isn't consistent with your `Fruit` interface?  Whether you explicitly depend on `Fruit` is irrelevant.

Comment: @JimmyJames I already said that `Orange` knows about `Fruit`. Will it help if I diagram it? `UsingCode`->`Fruit`<|-`Orange`. Notice that nothing is pointing at `Orange`? If you don't point at it you can be compiled without it.

Comment: @candied_orange I think you just need to read my first comment more carefully.  I said depending on `Orange` has an implicit dependency on `Fruit`.  This isn't controversial.  It's part of the definition of `Orange`.

Comment: @JimmyJames If you read my response to that comment carefully you'll see I was talking about avoiding doing that.  Your follow up question seems to insist that I'm talking about compiling `Orange` without `Fruit`. I'm not. I'm talking about compiling `UseingCode` without `Orange`. I've tried to make this clear 5 different ways now. I'm starting to lose faith in my ability to communicate.

Comment: @candied_orange That's great and all but it has nothing to do with *my* comment.   I'm not sure why you are addressing *my* comment and talking about something that doesn't have anything to do with *my* point.  *My* initial point was directed at the OP and has nothing to do with whatever you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare the variable by the most specific type `Orange`, the compiler will allow you to use (i.e. couple to) properties and/or methods declared in the `Orange` class, in addition to those declared in the Fruit class.

That means that if you later want to swap the Orange for a different fruit you will have more work to do, and if you or the maintainer of Orange wants to change or remove one of those properties or methods they may not be able to without breaking your new code.

When you declare the variable by the type `Fruit`, you only staticly couple to the things declared in the `Fruit` class, plus the constructor of Orange.

As Jacob said in comments this doesn't matter so much for local variables. If you don't want to couple to any property of Orange you can just not use it. It's more important for things passed between functions, like parameters, return values and properties.

I'm not a Java developer so I may be bringing in habits from PHP and Typescript, but personally I would be happy to let the compiler infer the type as Orange with `var obj=new Orange();`

Comment: Using `var obj = new Orange()` introduces the same coupling as `Orange obj = new Orange()`. Type inference doesn't guess which derived abstract type your code will end up using later on. It basically looks at the type returned from the right of the assignment operator.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes I realise that - it just removes the repetition of `Orange`. I'm agreeing with Jacob that for a local variable using the Orange type is basically fine. Do you think my answer is misleading or unclear?

Comment: I suppose if you can edit the Orange class you could also give it a static factory method with return type of `Fruit` and call that instead of `new Orange()`.

Comment: A constructor is basically a static factory method that returns a concrete type. Assigning it to a `Fruit` variable implicitly casts it up from Orange to Fruit. The static factory method doesn't add anything useful.

Comment: The only difference is the static factory method could return force the caller to use the Orange type - especially if all constructors on Orange were made private.

Comment: If you use orange methods and later change the object to apple, of course you have more work. But if declared as fruit, you wouldn’t have had access to the extra functionality in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. [Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) comes in many forms. And the number of classes your code knows about is absolutely one of those forms.

So if that form of coupling was the only thing to consider then the "Declare the most abstract type" advice loses to "Declare the exact type".

But you don't have to do it that way.

```
void ninja(Fruit fruit) {
.
.
.
}
```

There. For the cost of thinking of a name (`ninja`) you can avoid that whole coupling issue. No one has mentioned `Orange`. Nothing in this code cares if `Orange` exists. If an `Orange` comes along that can support the `Fruit` things `ninja` wants to do then fine, pass it in. But in this code we're certainly not running up your class count.

The main advantage of code like `Fruit obj=new Orange();` is that it sweeps the `Orange` aware code into a tight little corner that makes getting rid of the explicit reference to `Orange` easier later. Making the code work with this proves that the abstract `Fruit` works just fine for `ninja`. You can think of it as a first step to getting rid of references to `Orange`. But yeah, while `Orange` is still here you're still coupled to it.

Now something, somewhere will always have to know we're really dealing with an `Orange`. But if that code can be pushed off to another file then here at least we're free of that knowledge. Push it somewhere up the call stack away from our behavior code. It can go live with some boring structural configuration code.

Until you're ready to do all that, "declare the most abstract type", is a good way to get ready.

Comment: @wcminipgasker2023 And, if you designed the Fruit interface right (maybe after refining it through several iterations), passing in, say, a `new CandiedOrange` would not break the `ninja` method in any way. That's *what* makes it decoupled.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović true. Your ninja sword will need to be  sugar tolerant. ; )

Comment: Obviously I want an Orange. I just don’t want to write Orange specific code, so my mate who wants an Apple can use my code unchanged - except for initially requesting an Apple.

Comment: Until we introduce OrangeCandy.  No ninja sword can defeat that.

Answer (score 2):

If we consult the Dependency Inversion Principle, whose goal is to reduce coupling, it states:

1. High-level modules should not import anything from low-level
   modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).
2. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

This seems to indicate that coupling happens when we depend on concrete classes and not in interfaces, i.e., we depend on the design and not in the implementations. Of course in early stages an interface can change and will affect everything but after those initial stages interfaces are expected not to change as much as the implementations, and if you segregate the interfaces (Interface Segregation Principle) you protect yourself against that.

The more abstract something is, the less prone to change it is. So we should strive to depend on the things that change the less often, i.e., the more abstract components.

So the code that declares the variable as being a `Fruit` has less coupling than the one that declares it as being an `Orange`, **provided that you use some creational pattern to keep instantiations in a separate place**, perhaps a factory.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this for a while and posting a comment which maybe wasn't clear, I think this assertion is incorrect:

> Because I think "coupling" of a class is about counting how many other class names appeared in the source file, for example:

Perhaps there's a type of [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) which has been defined by the number of other classes referenced in a class, but if so, I don't think it's a useful or especially meaningful metric.  The reset of the answer will be an attempt to explain why.

In your original example, you compare the following two statements:

```
// option A
Fruit obj=new Orange();
// option B
Orange obj=new Orange();
```

Where `Orange` implements `Fruit`.

And you ask whether option A introduces more coupling than option **B**.  I would assert that at the very least there is no additional coupling in **A** versus **B**.  The reason is that in option **B**, the code is still coupled to the `Fruit` interface through a transitive dependency.  While it's possible that when using option **B**, you could use parts of `Orange` that are not part of `Fruit`, if you do that, **A** was never a viable option anyway.  I'll come back to this later.

To make this clear, consider what happens if the `Fruit` interface is modified when using option **B**: you will likely need to modify `Orange` as well, and those changes will potentially modify how you use `Orange` in your classes.  And if Fruit changes in a way that doesn't require changes to `Orange` (such as a default method) those still become part of `Orange`.  None of that changes when you explicitly type as `Fruit`.  Using `Orange` means using `Fruit`.  Using option **B** doesn't make you any less coupled to `Fruit`.

But wait, there's more.  I would actually argue that using Option **A** can increase your coupling.  The simple reason is that by using the `Fruit` type, you eliminate the possibility of coupling to other interfaces and classes aside from `Fruit`.  Let's say `Orange` also implements `Citrus`.  If you type your variable as `Orange` you are now transitively coupled to both interfaces, especially if you use those `Citrus` methods.  By using `Fruit`, you narrow the coupling to what `Fruit` provides.

I kind of hate these sorts of examples because trying to come up with meaningful methods that would make sense for a `Citrus` interface hurts my brain.  So instead, let's talk about `Collection` types.  This kind of thing is very relevant when using Collections in code.

```
// option A
Collection items = new ArrayList();
// option B
List items = new ArrayList();
// option C
ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
```

Where `ArrayList` implements `List`, and `List` implements `Collection`.

Which should we use?  As usual, the answer is (IMO) that you should use the most common (or more abstract) type that supports your needs.  If all you need is a `Collection` (i.e, you don't care about order or whether duplicate items can be added,) you should prefer `Collection` as your variable type.  If you need `List` capabilities as well, you should prefer `List`.  If for some reason you need to use `ArrayList` specific methods such as `trimToSize()`, then you should use that as your variable type (you have no choice, really.)

This minimizes your coupling to the simplest of the three that meets your needs.  This makes the code more obvious and simpler to modify later.